# my dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 laptop has heating issue while running on ubuntu?

Tags: windows-8.1, dell-inspiron, ubuntu-14.04, overheating

I have dual boot OS Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 and my laptop has little heating while running on Ubuntu, whereas windows has no such problems. Ubuntu forum suggest that this may happen due to graphic card issues or may be possible that it has ACPI (power saving) incompatibility.

My laptop config: Dell 15 3542 i7 Nvidia Geforce 840M, 2gb Intel HD controller(Haswell) 8gb DDR3L RAM ,1tb SATA HDD.

Please suggest how to troubleshoot.
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/225631/high-temperature-in-a-amd-radeon-hd4000-3000-series-after-upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Try different drivers for the video. I had the same problem before but tested some beta drivers and worked for me, buy usually in my experience with Ubuntu the laptop is hotter while running it but just a litle hotter in mater of 4-6 °C. Test, observe the temp and share glad if I can help :)